# How to prove the limit of a sequence using "$\epsilon-N$"

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

I think I have a proper understanding of the general procedure, but I'm having difficulty manipulating my inequality so that I can isolate $n$ by itself. Sadly I wasn't given many examples to model my answer on.

> Prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}=0$

So I'm given $L=0$. I then look at the inequality

$$\left| \frac{n+1}{n^2+1}-0\right|<\epsilon$$

but I have no idea how to isolate $n$. The best I can come up with, which may be the right idea, is to use another function $f$ such that

$$\left|\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}\right|<f<\epsilon$$

and then work with that. But my idea of using $f=\lvert n+1\rvert$ seems to have me a bit stuck too.

Comment: Nowhere in your start of the proof do you use $N$. Do you understand that $N$ and $n$ are different in $\epsilon-N$ proofs?

Comment: Given $\epsilon>0$ you need an $N$ such that for all $n>N$, $$\left|\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}\right|<\epsilon$$

Comment: Also, when writing a function $f$, you really ought to write :$$\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}<f(n)<\epsilon$$ Writing $f<\epsilon$ makes $f$ look like $f$ is a constant...

Comment: I was aware of those things, actually.. I was just trying to be concise in my question. I was getting specifically to the point I was having trouble with... but I think I solved it thanks to one example I found buried deep in my textbook. I posted it below.

Comment: Well, one reason to write longer is to make clear what you understand. People on M.SE have a lot of different experience levels, so when you skip crucial stuff or use odd notation, we have to guess if you understand it. Verbosity is not a crime. Indeed, it leads to better answers because people can tell what you know and what you don't know. Nothing is aided by writing $f$ instead of $f(n)$, or by confusing $n$ and $N$ in your text.

Answer (score 8):

Since the given sequence is positive for all $n\geq 1$, we can drop the absolute value signs.

Consider the inequality:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}<\epsilon
\end{equation*}
This is a messy inequality, as solving for $n$ would be rather difficult. Instead we shall find an upper bound for the numerator $(n+1)$ and a lower bound on the denominator $(n^2+1)$ so that we can construct a new sequence $f_{n}$ such that $$\frac{n+1}{n^{2}+1}<f_{n}<\epsilon.$$

Since $n+1$ behaves like $n$ at very large numbers, we shall try to find a value for $b$ such that $bn>n+1$. And since $n^{2}+1$ behaves like $n^{2}$ for very large numbers, we shall try to find a value for $c$ such that $cn^{2}<n^{2}+1$. $n+1<n+n=2n$ and $n^{2}+1>\frac{1}{2}n^{2}$ for all $n\geq 1$.

Now, consider the new inequality:
\begin{align*}
\frac{n+1}{n^{2}+1}<\frac{2n}{\frac{1}{2}n^{2}}<\frac{4}{n}<\epsilon
\end{align*}
We have 
\begin{equation*}
\frac{4}{n}<\epsilon\iff \frac{4}{\epsilon}<n
\end{equation*}

Let $\displaystyle N(\epsilon)=\lfloor4/\epsilon\rfloor$. Therefore, $\forall \epsilon>0,\ \exists N(\epsilon)=\lfloor4/\epsilon\rfloor\ni\forall n>N(\epsilon)$
\begin{align*}
\frac{n+1}{n^{2}+1}&<\frac{4}{n}<\frac{4}{N(\epsilon)+1}<\frac{4}{4/\epsilon}=\epsilon
\end{align*}

Comment: Yes, this works.

Comment: +1 good solution.  Using the lower bound $n^2 + 1 > n^2$ in stead of $n^2 + 1 > \frac12 n^2$ would be more efficient, but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Thanks. I was actually concerned about that myself, because it seemed my prof was writing that on the board... or maybe I thought he did, as I was writing it in my notes.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Show that $0<\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}<\frac{1}{n-1}$.

Comment: I'm sorry - I really don't understand what I'm supposed to do based on that hint. This is my first time trying to do this on my own so I don't have much of a foothold on the procedure yet.

Comment: Sorry, I always try to start with a hint.

Comment: Maybe you should try to prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n-1} =0?$$

Comment: Does my proposed solution below work?

Comment: Yes, your solution works. In my solution $N(\epsilon)=1+\lfloor 1/\epsilon\rfloor$. So if $n>N$ then $n-1>1/\epsilon$ so $\frac{1}{n-1}<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

The $\epsilon-N$ definition to $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=L$ is
$$
\big(
\forall \epsilon>0 
\big)
\big(
\exists N_{\epsilon}\in \mathbb{N}
\big)
\big[ 
(
\forall n\in \mathbb{N} 
)
( 
n>N_{\epsilon}
)
\implies
(
|a_n-L|<\epsilon
)
\big]
$$
That is, given an arbitrary, but fixed, $\epsilon>0$, we must find a candidate for $N_\epsilon\in\mathbb{N}$ with the property that 
$$
(\forall n\in \mathbb{N} 
)
( 
n>N_{\epsilon}
)
\implies
(
|a_n-L|<\epsilon
)
$$
The number $N_\epsilon$ also depends on the limit $L$ and the sequence itself as well. In this case, $L=0$ and 
$$
a_n= \frac{n+1}{n^2+1}.
$$
To find an $N_\epsilon$ candidate with the required property we must manipulate the inequality
$$
0-\epsilon< \frac{n+1}{n^2+1}< 0 +\epsilon.
$$
The inequality of the left is valid for all $\epsilon> 0$. Focus on the inequality of the right
$$
\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}< \epsilon.
$$
Note that
$
\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}
<
\frac{n+1}{n^2-1}
=
\frac{1}{n-1}
$ for $n\geq 2$. Once $\frac{1}{n-1}<\epsilon$ implies $\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}<\epsilon$, set 
$$
N_\epsilon =\min\left\{n\in\mathbb{N}: n>\frac{1}{\epsilon}+1 \mbox{ and } n\geq 2 \right\}
$$
In fact, 
\begin{align}
n>N_\epsilon \implies & n>\frac{1}{\epsilon}+1 \mbox{ and } n\geq 2
\\
\implies & n>\frac{1}{\epsilon}+1 \mbox{ and } n\geq 2
\\
\implies & \frac{1}{\epsilon}<n-1 \mbox{ and } n\geq 2
\\
\implies & n-1>\frac{1}{\epsilon} \mbox{ and } n\geq 2
\\
\implies & \frac{1}{n-1}<\epsilon \mbox{ and } n\geq 2
\\
\implies & \frac{n+1}{n+1}\cdot\frac{1}{n-1}<\epsilon
\\
\implies & \frac{n+1}{n^2-1}<\epsilon
\\
\implies & \frac{n+1}{n^2+1}<\epsilon 
\\
\implies & -\epsilon< \frac{n+1}{n^2+1}< \epsilon.
\\
\implies & \left|\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}\right|< \epsilon.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Fairly crude  bounds or estimates can be very useful in simplifying  problems about limits. For example if $n\geq 1$ then $$0<\frac {n+1}{n^2+1}=\frac {n(1+n^{-1})}{n^2(1+n^{-2})}=\left(\frac {1}{n}\right)\cdot \frac {1+n^{-1}}{1+n^{-2}}\leq \left( \frac {1}{n}\right) \cdot\frac {2}{1+n^{-2}}< \left(\frac {1}{n}\right)\cdot\frac {2}{1}=\frac {2}{n}.$$ So if $\epsilon >0$ and $n\geq \max (1,\frac {2}{\epsilon})$ then $|\frac {n+1}{n^2+1}|<\epsilon.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon <1$ then $$\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}<\epsilon \Leftrightarrow \epsilon n^2-n-(1-\epsilon)>0$$

You can solve this inequeality like a quadratic polinomial and you can find that for $$\forall n\geqslant n_0=[\frac{1+2\sqrt{\epsilon(1-\epsilon)}}{2}]+1 \Rightarrow \frac{n+1}{n^2+1}<\epsilon$$ forall $\epsilon<1$.

Thus we found an appropraite $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$,which depends on $\epsilon$, such that $\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}<\epsilon,\forall n\geqslant n_0$

This is a way to prove it
but indeed it is easier to find a simpler sequence $b_n$ such that $\frac{n+1}{n^2+1} \leqslant b_n<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Examining $\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}$ you realize that as $n$ grows it will start 'acting like' $1/n$. You know the quadratic formula, and after a bit of tinkering you guess that the key is analyzing

$\tag 1 \frac{n+1}{n^2+1} \le \frac{2}{n}$

The inequality (1) is equivalent to

$\tag 2 n^2 - n + 2 \ge 0$

The discriminant for this quadratic expression is negative, so it is always true.

Let the $\varepsilon \gt 0$ challenge be presented. Then $2/n \lt \varepsilon$ iff $n \gt 2/\varepsilon$.

Select any natural number $N$ greater than $2/\varepsilon$.

We have shown that if $n \ge N$, $\frac{n+1}{n^2+1} \lt \varepsilon$, and the proof of convergence had been demonstrated.