# Use the $\epsilon-$K definition to show that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I know that you need to use the Archimedean Property, and what I've thought is that if we have $\epsilon > 0$ as a given, and we know $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}$, but I am not quite sure what to do next.

Comment: instead of this , choose $N> \frac{1}{\epsilon^2}$

Comment: You're almost there. By Archimedean Property, for any $\epsilon$ you can find $n$ such that $0<\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon^2$. Take square roots and you'll be dealing with the sequence you want

Comment: Have a look at : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507897/how-to-prove-the-limit-of-a-sequence-using-epsilon-n . it nicely explains how it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prove the limit of a sequence using "$\epsilon-N$"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507897/how-to-prove-the-limit-of-a-sequence-using-epsilon-n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the nice explanation from abbott:[image]