# Using the Epsilon-N Definition of limits of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

I think I have a proper understanding of the general procedure, but I'm having difficulty manipulating my inequality so that I can isolate $n$ by itself. Sadly I wasn't given many examples to model my answer on.

> Prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n(n-1)} = 0.$$

Comment: "$\epsilon$-$N$" proofs generally do not rest upon "isolating" $n$, or identifying the optimal set of $n$ that will satisfy the desired goal for a given $\epsilon$. You can make a lot of sacrifices to sub-optimality as long as, given $\epsilon$, you can produce some value of $N$ for which the desired condition (which you might write out as the first line of your proof as a desired end result) holds for $n \geq N$. This simplifies a lot of proofs. You do **not** have to optimize, you only need to satisfy the definition.

Comment: Assuming that the sequence converges to $L$, and given $\epsilon > 0$ you want to specify $N$, in terms of $\epsilon$ such that $~\forall ~n > N, ~|a_n - L| < \epsilon.$

Comment: lol did you just verbatim copy the first paragraph from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507897/how-to-prove-the-limit-of-a-sequence-using-epsilon-n?rq=1 ? Perhaps a better way to help people who are writing answers for you in future would be to write a little paragraph yourself about how you read that question and tried apply it to your own question, and where you got stuck or confused with that.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\dfrac{1}{n(n-1)} < \dfrac{1}{n}$.